# My function inside innerHTML not working its say when i click the button the function is not defined

Tags: javascript

Hello can someone help me thanks i don't know what's wrong.

```js
var state = false;

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("button");
  state = !state;
  if (state) {
    x.value = "ON";
  } else {
    x.value = "OFF";
  }
}

const rootApp = document.getElementById("root");
rootApp.innerHTML = '<input id="button" value="ON" type="button" onclick="myFunction()" />';
```

Comment: Did you find out? If not feel free to let me know where you're stuck

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-59jht?from-embed=&file=/src/index.js, you can view it here it is still not working i dunno why :(

Comment: Your code is all commented out, remove the `//` at the beginning of each line for starters :)

Comment: Look at my answer, and use the code I gave, it will work

Comment: yes it works if i'm gonna include it on an .html file but i'm building it at .js file

Comment: can you see my codesandbox above please so you will understand what i'm saying thanks :(

Comment: Wait, I forked your codesandbox and made it work, see link at the end of my answer

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
      var state = false;
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("button");
        state = !state;
        if (state) {
          x.value = "ON";
        } else {
          x.value = "OFF";
        }
      }
    
      const rootApp = document.getElementById("root");
      rootApp.innerHTML = '<input id="button" value="ON" type="button" onclick="myFunction()" />';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi sir how about it is not embedded in an .html file just a .js file

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is a `#root` element in your document? Is the javascript code located in the `head` or in the `body`?

The code you gave works fine already if you copy/paste it into your console on this page and target `document.body` within `rootApp` instead of `document.getElementById("root");` so I suspect your problem happens because of something external to it.

**Additionally**

1. If you use `const` you should use `let` instead of `var`, since you're declaring `state` in the top level scope, it will be accessible within any nested scopes (your function's body)
2. If you don't care about (3) you can access the button by passing `this` to `myFunction` within the `onclick` attribute, doing so eliminates the need to use `getElementById` inside `myFunction` as it will be given as an argument
3. It's better to create the button element yourself and use `addEventListener` to add interactivity instead of using `innerHTML`

As a bonus, this could be improved by using a `checkbox` instead of a button: you wouldn't have to synchronize the checked state all the time.   You can always [style the checkbox to look like something else using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css)

**Reworked code**

```js
let state = false;

function myFunction({ target }) {
  state = !state;
  target.value = state ? 'ON' : 'OFF';
}

// Let's try to get the #root element
const rootId = 'root';
let rootApp = document.getElementById(rootId);

// If you don't have a #root element, we can create one
if (!rootApp) {
  rootApp = document.createElement('div');
  rootApp.id = rootId;
  document.body.appendChild(rootApp);
}

// Create the button element and setup its attributes
const element = document.createElement('input');
element.type = 'button';
element.id = 'button';

// Make sure `value` is in sync with `state`
element.value = state ? 'ON' : 'OFF';

// Listen to click event
element.addEventListener('click', myFunction);

// Append to #root
rootApp.appendChild(element);
```

[Here is a working CodeSandbox forked from yours and updated with my js](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-forked-r73iq?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: thank you sir got it it's finally working

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer :)